# How do use zoomIn feature using CSS3

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create the zoomIn effect like this page: [**Example Website**](http://matthiaskretschmann.com/)

The top "mk" logo zooms in on page load.

I tried to copy the code and this is what I have so far but it's not working:

html:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="toplogo"><h1><a href="http://www.pz.com">PagesByZ:: Think Outside the Box</a></h1></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#header {
    width: 800px;
    height: 80px;
    animation: 0.4s ease-in-out 0s normal forwards 1 zoomIn;
}
#toplogo h1 { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
}
#toplogo h1 a { 
    display: block; 
    width: 212px; 
    height: 80px; 
    margin: 20px 0 0; 
    background: url('http://www.interfaithmedical.com/pz/theImages/hdrLogo.png') no-repeat; 
    color: #fff; 
    font-size: 40px; 
    font-weight: 400; 
    outline: none; 
    text-indent: -10000px; 
}
```

JDFiddle example: **http://jsfiddle.net/n75rL/**

I am trying to accomplish that effect on my logo each time the page loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean "zoom out".

You're missing the actual animation list definition:

```
@keyframes zoomIn{
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(10);
  }
  100% {              /* <- not really required if these are the defaults */
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
```

And it appears that you're using the wrong shorthand property format (see the syntax section [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation)).

(here's an updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C9kSL/1/))

Comment: Do I have to add it to the webpage before I can see the animation? The JSFiddle doesn't show any animation.

Comment: I added the code in my webpage but the image is not doing the animation.

Comment: I updated your reply with the missing '}' and Thanks! it's working now! i know IE does not support it so I won't even bother :P

Comment: Works in IE 10. For IE 9 I think you need to use the `-ms-` prefix

Comment: Yes I am still running IE 8 for testing purposes.